# Javascript: when new a Promise instance, where are the parameters(resolve,reject) from

Tags: javascript

when I learn the concept about Promise, I see the below sample code.

```js
new Promise( (resolve,reject) => { // who pass this two function resolve and reject ??
    setTimeout( () => {
        resolve("find this paramter function");
    }, 5000)
})
```

**" when new a Promise instance, where are the parameters(resolve,reject) from ?? "**

The above question bothers me a lot, so I want to understand it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It’s callback arguments. There’s nothing special about them.

Comment: Same as with every other callback. Do you know "who" does call the function? They're the ones who create the resolving functions and pass them.